# using ng-show and ng-repeat at the same time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Shouldn't this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href ng-click="app.selectTab(1)">Cranves-Sales</a></li>
<li><a href ng-click="app.selectTab(2)">Epagny</a></li>
</ul>
```

Be the same as this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li ng-repeat="magasin in app.magasins">
<a ng-repeat="magasin in app.magasins" href ng-click="app.selectTab({{magasin.tab}})">{{magasin.name}}</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I have the angular controller on the body of the page, since its a small website, its working when I use app.selectTab(1) for example, but it shouldn't be a problem since I'm using the same login behind ng-show on the main div with `ng-show="app.isSelectedTab({{magasin.tab}})"`

Here is my app controller:

```
app.controller('appController', function () {
    this.products = products;
    this.magasins = magasins;
    //PAGE
    this.page = 2;
    this.selectPage = function (setPage) {
        this.page = setPage;
    };
    this.isSelectedPage = function (checkPage) {
        return this.page === checkPage;
    };
    //TAB
    this.tab = 2;
    this.selectTab = function (setTab) {
        this.page = 2;
        this.tab = setTab;
    };
    this.isSelectedTab = function (checkTab) {
        return this.tab === checkTab;
    };
});
var magasins = [{
    name: 'Cranves Sales',
    tab: '1'

}, {
    name: 'Epagny',
    tab: '2'
} ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ehh - not really. You only need 1 `ngRepeat` on the `<li>` - and when you pass in the value to the `ngClick` you dont need the `{{}}`

```
<li ng-repeat="magasin in app.magasins">
    <a href ng-click="app.selectTab(magasin.tab)">{{magasin.name}}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Holy, thank you lol, I actually had it with one ng-repeat, but have been trying a lot of things to get around this and kinda went thought when posting here, didn't know the '{{}}' weren't needed in those cases, thank you again sir!